# Pandas: Cosine similarity for each rows

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity

I have dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['apple', 'one', 0.0, [0.047668457, -0.04888916]], ['banana', 'two', 0.0 , [0.0287323, -0.037841797] ], ['qiwi', 'three', 0.0, [0.031051636, -0.05227661]],
        ['orange', 'one', 1.0, [0.0020618439, -0.055389404]], ['mango', 'two', 1.0, [0.0030326843, -0.036193848]], ['strawberry', 'three', 1.0, [0.008613586, -0.06561279]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['word', 'group', 'count', 'vec'])
----------+-----+-----+--------------------+----------+
|      word|group|count|                 vec|     word2|
+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+----------+
|     apple|  one|  0.0|[0.047668457, -0....|     apple|
|    banana|  two|  0.0|[0.0287323, -0.03...|    banana|
|      qiwi|three|  0.0|[0.031051636, -0....|      qiwi|
|    orange|  one|  1.0|[0.0020618439, -0...|    orange|
|     mango|  two|  1.0|[0.0030326843, -0...|     mango|
|strawberry|three|  1.0|[0.008613586, -0....|strawberry|
+----------+-----+-----+--------------------+----------+
```

I want to create a 5x5 dataframe where the cosine  similarity of each row will be calculated. Result look like this(I showed only 2 lines in the example):

```
   +------+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
    |  word|     apple|    banana|              qiwi|            orange|             mango|        strawberry|
    +------+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
    | apple|       1.0|0.99240247|0.9721006775103194|0.7414623055821596|0.7414623055821596|0.8007656107780402|
    |banana|0.99240247|       1.0|        0.99357443|        0.81838407|        0.84415172|          0.868376|
    +------+----------+----------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
                                   ...........................
```

I tried this, but i dont know how to fill all None:

```
df['word2'] = df['word']
df_piv = df.pivot_table(index=['word'], columns='word2',
                         values='vec', aggfunc='first').reset_index()
# calc cos sim
# df2 = df_piv .set_index('word')
# v = cosine_similarity(df2.values)

# done = pd.DataFrame(v, columns=df2.index.values, index=df2.index).reset_index()
        +----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
        |      word|               apple|              banana|               mango|              orange|                qiwi|          strawberry|
        +----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
        |     apple|[0.047668457, -0....|                null|                null|                null|                null|                null|
        |    banana|                null|[0.0287323, -0.03...|                null|                null|                null|                null|
        |     mango|                null|                null|[0.0030326843, -0...|                null|                null|                null|
        |    orange|                null|                null|                null|[0.0020618439, -0...|                null|                null|
        |      qiwi|                null|                null|                null|                null|[0.031051636, -0....|                null|
        |strawberry|                null|                null|                null|                null|                null|[0.008613586, -0....|
        +----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use sklearn cosine_similarity module:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

vectors = df['vec'].to_list()
pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(vectors, vectors), 
             index=df['word'], columns=df['word'])
```

Output would be:

```
word    apple   banana  qiwi    orange  mango   strawberry
word                        
apple   1.000000    0.992402    0.972101    0.741462    0.771779    0.800766
banana  0.992402    1.000000    0.993574    0.818384    0.844152    0.868376
qiwi    0.972101    0.993574    1.000000    0.878167    0.899404    0.918923
orange  0.741462    0.818384    0.878167    1.000000    0.998924    0.995648
mango   0.771779    0.844152    0.899404    0.998924    1.000000    0.998899
strawberry  0.800766    0.868376    0.918923    0.995648    0.998899    1.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cdist` from `scipy.spatial.distance`:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist


vecs = df['vec'].to_list()
pd.DataFrame(1 - cdist(vecs, vecs, metric='cosine'), 
             index=df['word'], columns=df['word'])
```

Output:

```
word           apple    banana      qiwi    orange     mango  strawberry
word                                                                    
apple       1.000000  0.992402  0.972101  0.741462  0.771779    0.800766
banana      0.992402  1.000000  0.993574  0.818384  0.844152    0.868376
qiwi        0.972101  0.993574  1.000000  0.878167  0.899404    0.918923
orange      0.741462  0.818384  0.878167  1.000000  0.998924    0.995648
mango       0.771779  0.844152  0.899404  0.998924  1.000000    0.998899
strawberry  0.800766  0.868376  0.918923  0.995648  0.998899    1.000000
```